# TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined from the Array using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am trying to create a webpage where when a user logs in from the login page, my page that is the 'user management' page should display users belonging to the login user's company.

For eg: When a user belonging to company APPLE logs in, this webpage should only display users belonging to APPLE.

In the code, "currentUser" is the login user I get from the login page via localStorage getItem. "allUsers" array is the list of all users from different companies. Empty array "user" should display only display Current user's company's-users from the list of allUsers.

For that I have used FOR LOOP seen at the end of the JS file. I'm getting a error that the property 'company' is undefined. Looking for someone to help me. Thanks in advance.

```
  var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

    myApp.controller("myController", function ($scope) {
        console.log("in controller...");
        $scope.newUser = {};
        $scope.info = "";

        if ($scope.users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users")) !== null) {

            $scope.users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users"));
        }

        if (localStorage.getItem("currentUser") !== null) {

            var currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"));
            console.log("Received");
        }
        else {
            console.log("Not received");
        }

        if (localStorage.getItem("allUsers") === null) {
            $scope.allUsers = [
                { email: "John@yahoo.com", password:"John123", firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", contact: "281-283-2480", role: "Supplier-Admin", company: "Apple" },
                { email: "Rick@yahoo.com", password: "Rick123", firstName: "Rick", lastName: "Fraiser", contact: "987-283-2489", role: "Supplier-User", company: "Apple" },
                { email: "Sam@yahoo.com", password: "Sam123", firstName: "Sam", lastName: "Tarly", contact: "456-786-2480", role: "BuyerAdmin", company: "Samsung" }
            ];
            localStorage.setItem("allUsers", JSON.stringify($scope.allUsers));
            // localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify($scope.users));
        } else {
            $scope.allUsers = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allUsers"));
        }

        //filter allUsers based on currentUser's role
        for (var i = 0; $scope.allUsers.length; i++) {
            $scope.users = [{}];
            if ($scope.allUsers[i].company === currentUser[0].company) {
                $scope.users.push($scope.allUser[i]);
            }
            localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify($scope.users));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your `currentUser` may be `undefined`. Check your condition in the retrieving of your currentUser from the localstorage.

Comment: The currentUser array does show in the localStorage in the browser developer tools. And I also get the console message "Received" under the if (localStorage.getItem("currentUser") != null) statement.

Comment: Maybe, but you should add a condition. And I don't see a declaration of your `i` variable.
You should clean your localstorage, because residual things of what you did before may stay in your variables.

Comment: @Sw0ut I did clear localStorage, still no good. I don't understand what do you mean by- "And I don't see a declaration of your i variable".   I can say that the code certainly gets the currentUser data because it shows the message "Received". If i clear the CurrentUser data and run again, I get "Not received".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localStorage.getItem() returns string representation of null, if the key has null value in localStorage so your null check might not be behaving like expected. I'd recommend to wrap getItem in a function that would check that.

```
function(itemName) {
  const item = localStorage.getItem(itemName);
  return item === 'null'
    ? null
    : item;
}
```

Your problem is probably in the place where you set currentUser, maybe because of the same null check.

Also try declaring your i variable in for loop.

```
for(var i = 0; ...) ...
```

**Edit**

There seems to be an error in this line

```
if ($scope.allUsers[i].company === currentUser[0].company) {
  $scope.users.push($scope.allUser[i]);
}
```

You're trying to push $scope.allUser[I] which is not defined, you've probably meant to write $scope.allUsers[I].

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. Getting the same error message 'Comapny' undefined.

Comment: Could you change, console.log("Received");, to console.log("Received", currentUser); and show us the output? Did you check your spelling and case?

Comment: When i use this, console.log("Received", currentUser);, I get Array(0) with all the columns like Email, name, contact, company....along with their details. So that means the data does get received from the stroage right?

Comment: So currentUser is an array then. You should then access it like one. currentUser[0].company

Comment: Oh you are right! But unfortunately, I am now getting '0' as undefined :(

Comment: In which line error occurs? Did you try declaring your index variable as for( var i = 0; ... ?

Comment: This answer has a misstatement; [`localStorage.getItem()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) *will return null* if a key is not present in storage.

Comment: You're right, I've edited my answer with better explanation.

Comment: The line error seems to occur in $scope.users.push($scope.allUser[i]); yes, I used for(var i=0;...)

Comment: It's still not quite correct. `getItem('key')` will return `"null"` if someone has used `setItem('key', null)`, because you cannot set an item to `null` in `localStorage`. I mean, it will also return '"null"' if they use `setItem('key', 'null')`, but that's just silly :).

Comment: I don't understand. If it returns null, the the consoleLog should display "Not received" message from the else statement right? So are you suggesting me to use a key? How do I do that? Please explain.

Comment: I've updated my answer to make it a bit clearer what I meant. @Vaibhav Shankar I've edited my answer pointing out  your mistake which is probably causing your error.